# "command 'agda-mode.input-symbol[BrowseLeft]' not found" error in VSCode everytime I try to browse now with arrow keys

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, agda, vscode-keybinding, agda-mode

I have no idea what happened. I was doing some Agda work in one window, and I had a C project in another. Restarted VS Code to work on the C project, now every time I try to use arrow keys I get the error message mentioned in the title, and my cursor won't move.

I looked at my Keyboard shortcuts and found this:
[image: List of keyboard shortcuts concerning arrow keys and agda-mode]

Disabling the extension and restarting didn't work.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/banacorn/agda-mode-vscode/blob/master/package.json#L735 and https://github.com/banacorn/agda-mode-vscode/blob/da1870db12bf06001e5f0f36763b8d0d949f93bb/src/State/State__Type.res#L120

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happened (either), but somehow your extension-scoped settings got copied over to your user-scoped keybindings config file, and they got copied over without copying over the [when clauses](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts), so they're applying at all times, in all contexts (that's why disabling the extension and restarting didn't work: the copied keybindings in your user-scoped keybindings were still active, and were then pointing to commands defined by a disabled extension).

To fix the issue right now, you should delete those copied-over keybindings from your keybindings config file (`Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the command palette).